Why print can change the Fortran results?
It is a rather simple but frustrating question. I have written UMAT with ABAQUS, and part codes are as follows,
      macro_strain(:) = 0 
      macro_strain(1:3) = DSTRAN
      !print * , 'macro_strain', macro_strain

The ABAQUS will no converge.
Howvere, if I do not comment the last line,
      macro_strain(:) = 0 
      macro_strain(1:3) = DSTRAN
      print * , 'macro_strain', macro_strain

Everything works well. I have predefined the relevant variables as,
      REAL*8 :: STRAN(NTENS), STATEV(NSTATV),STRESS(NTENS), DDSDDE(NTENS
     1,NTENS), DSTRAN(NTENS)      
      REAL*8 :: macro_strain

Is there anyway do not print the last line?
Thanks for any advice.

This kind of weird behavior often happens because of a bug in the code, and how this bug comes out may depend on unrelated parts of the code. You should try compiling with all warning and runtime checks enabled to have a chance catching the bug: with Intel Fortran is it "-warn -check"

BTW, in what you have pasted here, macro_strain is declared as a scalar, but used as an array. This should not compile at all.

Please create a real [mcve]. It is possible, that you will find the bug during the process of creating it. If not, others will be able to help. Without the code, no one can directly help.

Is NTENS == 3 ? But a second to both PierU and Vladimir, use the compiler to help yourself, and without a minimal reproducible example it is very difficult to help.

Clarify what you mean by 'ABAQUS will no converge'. Provide error messages or more context.
